# Add Ideas object in community custom template - Napili

Tags: community, community-builder

16'winter Napili template releases new function - add custom objects. I was trying to add idea object in navi tab but ideas object don't show in salesforce object list. So, I tried to new a page and choose idea object. but i saw the error message "Looks like there's a problem.This record isn't supported. See your administrator for help."

Has anyone experience to deal with it ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideas standard object are not yet supported in Napili template .Check below from Ideas portal

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DtvIAAS

Currently only below are supported

> Accounts, cases, contacts, and custom objects.

Is your idea object custom?

Answer (score -1):

There is a free component for in on AppExchange

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000E9l50UAB